# How to bind WPF ItemsControl source to list segment

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `ItemsControl` that is bound to a list of elements. How can I have it display only a segment of that list, say, based on a given `Offset` and `Count` ?

Obviously I could declare an `IEnumerable` property as `MyList.Skip(Offset).Take(Count)`, use that in the binding and notify `PropertyChanged` each time `Offset` or `Count` are modified.  That works fine, except that each time the `ItemsControl` would recreate the views for all of its items, even for those that aren't new.

I guess a more idiomatic way would be to have a `CollectionView` but it doesn't seem to support the concept of current segment. I tried to use an index-based filter but besides from feeling wrong, it suffers from the same performance problem as before.

So the only way I saw so far was to maintain an `ObservableCollection` with the correct list elements and use this in the binding, but shouldn't there be an easier way?

Here's my test program (I know the code for `MyObservableCollection` does not work in the general case)

1. `MainWindow.xaml`

```cs
<Window x:Class="ItemsControlSegmentView.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemsControlSegmentView"
        x:Name="This"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="{Binding DataContext.CurrentColor, ElementName=This, Mode=OneTime}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyEnumerable}"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionView}"/>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Slider Maximum="{Binding MyList.Count}" Value="{Binding Offset}"/>
        <Slider Maximum="{Binding MaxCount}" Value="{Binding Count}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

2. `MainWindowViewModel`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Data;
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace ItemsControlSegmentView
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private int offset;
        private int count = 7;
        private readonly Random random = new Random();

        public string CurrentColor { get; private set; } = "White";

        public int Offset
        {
            get { return offset; }
            set
            {
                if (offset == value) return;
                var atEnd = value > offset;
                offset = value;
                UpdateAllViews(atEnd);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MaxCount));
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int Count
        {
            get { return count; }
            set
            {
                if (count == value) return;
                count = value;
                UpdateAllViews(true);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public int MaxCount => MyList.Count - Offset;

        public List<string> MyList { get; } = new List<string>(Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayOfWeek)));

        private void UpdateAllViews(bool atEnd)
        {
            CurrentColor = $"#{random.Next():X8}";
            UpdateMyEnumerable();
            UpdateMyCollectionView();
            UpdateMyObservableCollection(atEnd);
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> MyEnumerable => MyList.Skip(Offset).Take(Count);
        private void UpdateMyEnumerable() => OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MyEnumerable));

        public ListCollectionView MyCollectionView { get; }
        private void UpdateMyCollectionView() => MyCollectionView.Filter = entry =>
        {
            var indexOf = MyList.IndexOf((string)entry);
            return indexOf >= Offset && indexOf < Offset + Count;
        };

        public ObservableCollection<string> MyObservableCollection { get; }
        private void UpdateMyObservableCollection(bool atEnd)
        {
            foreach (var s in MyList.Except(MyEnumerable))
                MyObservableCollection.Remove(s);
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var s in MyEnumerable.Except(MyObservableCollection))
                if (atEnd) MyObservableCollection.Add(s);
                else MyObservableCollection.Insert(i++, s);
        }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            MyCollectionView = new ListCollectionView(MyList);
            MyObservableCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>(MyList);
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the window looks like after having scrolled the offset slider to the right end and back, step by step. Only the third `ItemsControl` keeps its existing entries:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: As you said. You can filter a collectionview, use linq to build a collection or you can write some other way. Like translate your collection into a parent - child collection so you pick a month and within that current item there's a collection of days-of-that-month.

Comment: BTW as posed your question seems to be asking people if their opinion is that there should morally be some "better" way of grouping within csharp or wpf. SO questions cannot be opinion based and should be very specific with absolute answers. Good luck.

Comment: The question is whether there's a another way of doing this, different from what I already tried, ideally more elegant but without the described performance impact

Comment: The canonical implementation would be the `ObservableCollection`. If your scenario requires you to have even more performance, I would suggest taking a look at [virtualization](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/albulank/2009/11/12/data-and-ui-virtualization-in-wpf/).